# Add float type field in Sql update query

Tags: mysql, sql

i am using below query for update value

```
UPDATE cfbnv_rg_lead_detail SET value='Address' WHERE lead_id='175' && form_id='1' && CAST(field_number AS DECIMAL) = CAST(4.2 AS DECIMAL).
```

this query working but it also update value where  field_number = 4.3 and field_number = 4.4 .

field_number field type is float.

did I do wrong?

Thanks 
Ballu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are casting to `DECIMAL`, which has no decimal.

You need to add (M,D) to `DECIMAL(M,D)`.

```
mysql> select CAST(4.3 AS DECIMAL);
+----------------------+
| CAST(4.3 AS DECIMAL) |
+----------------------+
|                    4 |
+----------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select CAST(4.3 AS DECIMAL(10,5));
+----------------------------+
| CAST(4.3 AS DECIMAL(10,5)) |
+----------------------------+
|                    4.30000 |
+----------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select CAST(4.3 AS DECIMAL(10,5)) = CAST(4.2 AS DECIMAL(10,5));
+---------------------------------------------------------+
| CAST(4.3 AS DECIMAL(10,5)) = CAST(4.2 AS DECIMAL(10,5)) |
+---------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                       0 |
+---------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

-- Add some decimal
UPDATE cfbnv_rg_lead_detail SET value='Address' WHERE lead_id='175' && form_id='1' && CAST(field_number AS DECIMAL(10,5)) = CAST(4.2 AS DECIMAL(10,5)).
```